# PascalABCNet, при перезапуске кода функция вызывается два раза

Tags: pascal, pascalabc.net

Вчера сделал калькулятор, нажал на кнопку *проверить здоровье кода* и увидел, что у меня было 64% из-за устаревших конструкций. Я почитай официальную документацию, переписал код. Теперь здоровье кода показывало 134%, но при вводе знака, после перезапуска программы, функция с проверкой на правильно введённый знак перезапускается два раза, а после можно снова пользоваться программой. Вот вывод:

```
Введите знак(/,*,+,-): *
Введите первое число:  1
Введите второе число:  2
Ответ: 2
Введите знак(/,*,+,-): Вы используете несуществующий символ для вычисления!
Введите знак(/,*,+,-): Вы используете несуществующий символ для вычисления!
Введите знак(/,*,+,-):
```

Обновленный код:

```
{program calculator;}
label restart;
begin
  var rest: integer;
  restart: rest := 0;
  while rest <> 1 do
  begin
    var sign := ReadChar('Введите знак(/,*,+,-):');
    if (sign <> '-') and (sign <> '+') and (sign <> '/') and (sign <> '*') then begin
      writeln('Вы используете несуществующий символ для вычисления!');
      goto restart;
    end;
    var a := ReadInteger('Введите первое число: ');
    var b := ReadInteger('Введите второе число: ');
    if sign = '+' then begin
      writeln('Ответ: ', a + b);
    end;
    if sign = '-' then begin
      writeln('Ответ: ', a - b);
    end;
    if sign = '/' then begin
      if b <> 0 then begin
        writeln('Ответ: ', a / b);
      end
      else
    writeln('Нельзя делить на 0!');
      goto restart;
    end;
    if sign = '*' then begin
      writeln('Ответ: ', a * b);
    end;
  end;
end.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело в том, что функция `ReadChar()` принимает на вход все символы, введенные пользователем, включая Enter, который состоит из двух [символов CrLf (Carriage return + Line feed) — это комбинация двух символов: возврата каретки и перевода строки. Они используются в системах Windows и DOS. Символ возврата каретки возвращает курсор в начало строки, а символ перевода строки переносит курсор на новую строку.](https://uchet-jkh.ru/i/cto-takoe-zamena-simvolov-lf-na-crlf/#:%7E:text=%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8B%20CrLf%20(Carriage%20return%20%2B%20Line,%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%20%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%8E%20%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83.))
Если вы немного измените строку вывода сообщения о недопустимом символе:

```
writeln('Вы используете несуществующий символ для вычисления с кодом ['+ord(sign) + ']!');
```

то сможете это проверить.
Как с этим бороться?
После ряда экспериментов с `ReadChar()`, `ReadLn()`, `ReadlnChar()` сложилось впечатление, что PascalABC не приспособлен для ввода данных в цикле (или у меня такая реализация IDE), поскольку буфер ввода с клавиатуры не очищается перед следующим вводом и туда проскакивают как минимум CrLf.
Возможно, существуют функции / процедуры, которые очищают буфер ввода с клавиатуры перед следующим вводом, но я таких не нашел.
Сделал более-менее стабильно (у меня) работающий вариант:

```
{program calculator;}
var
  signs: set of char := ['+', '-', '*', '/']; // задаем множество допустимых символов
  a, b: Integer;
  buf: string;
  sign: char;

begin
  while True do
  begin
    buf := '';
    write('Введите знак(/,*,+,-) или # для выхода: ');
    while buf = '' do Readln(buf);
    sign := buf[1];
    if sign = '#' then break;
    if sign in signs then // проверяем, допустим ли символ - есть ли он во множестве
    begin
      a := ReadInteger('Введите первое число: ');
      b := ReadInteger('Введите второе число: ');
      case sign of  // вместо нескольких if
        '+': writeln('Ответ: ', a + b);
        '-': writeln('Ответ: ', a - b);
        '/':
          begin
            if b <> 0 then writeln('Ответ: ', a / b)
            else writeln('Нельзя делить на 0!');
          end;
        '*': writeln('Ответ: ', a * b);
      end;
    end
    else writeln('Вы используете несуществующий символ для вычисления с кодом [' + ord(sign) + ']!'); // выводим не только сообщение, но и ASCII - код недопустимого символа (для отладки, например)
  end;
  writeln('Калькулятор выключен');
end.
```

```
Введите знак(/,*,+,-) или # для выхода: +
Введите первое число:  1
Введите второе число:  3
Ответ: 4
Введите знак(/,*,+,-) или # для выхода: 45
Вы используете несуществующий символ для вычисления с кодом [52]!
Введите знак(/,*,+,-) или # для выхода: /
Введите первое число:  45
Введите второе число:  5
Ответ: 9
Введите знак(/,*,+,-) или # для выхода: *
Введите первое число:  25
Введите второе число:  45
Ответ: 1125
Введите знак(/,*,+,-) или # для выхода: *89
Введите первое число:  
78
Введите второе число:  88
Ответ: 6864
Введите знак(/,*,+,-) или # для выхода: #
Калькулятор выключен
```